# find and replace string in all mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, replace

I have a mongodb database named "eagle" and am trying to replace all email records of "blue@domain.com" with "pink@domain.com"  (within collection "all collections".

```
db.eagle.find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    e.email=e.email.replace("//blue@domain.com","//pink@domain.com");
    db.eagle.save(e);
});
```

I am very new to mongodb...so I'm not even sure that I'm in "eagle" or "falcon"....I just run mongo.  This query doesn't do anything.

Here is what my Communications object looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("redacted"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-03T15:08:07.000Z"),
    "thread_index" : "",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-09-01T17:49:31.401Z"),
    "from" : {
        "username" : "None",
        "name" : "Pinky Jones",
        "email" : "blue@domain.com"
    },
    "to" : {
        "username" : "redude",
        "name" : "Red Baron",
        "email" : "red@domain.com"
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-01T17:49:31.401Z"),

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findAndModify` instead `find`

[Documentación findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Comment: TypeError: db.eagle.findandmodify is not a function :